# How to run a driver found on GitHub?

Tags: ros, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm new to Ubuntu and especially to ROS.

I use the thermal camera A65 from FLIR and found a driver [here](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/flir_gige).

How do I download and run this driver on ROS? Could somebody give me the exact comands I have to type in, beginning on opening the terminal the first time?

I'm very frustrated, because I need to use the camera with ROS but can't even follow the README on the repository..

Thank you very very much in advance!

**Edit:**
ROS-Version: Jade Turtle;
Ubuntu-Version: 14.04

**Update:**
If I do a catkin_make in ´./catkin_ws´ I get the following error. How can I solve this?

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'flir_gige'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(flir_gige)
CMake Error at flir_gige/cmake/FindEbus.cmake:58 (message):
  Failed to find ebus - Could not find ebus include directory, set
  Ebus_INCLUDE_DIR to path to ebus include directory,e.g.
  /opt/pleora/ebus_sdk/Ubuntu-12.04-x86_64/include.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  flir_gige/cmake/FindEbus.cmake:87 (Ebus_REPORT_NOT_FOUND)
  flir_gige/CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nina/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/nina/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Fehler 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed*
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232687/how-to-run-a-driver-found-on-github?/) by [ninamekaw](https://answers.ros.org/users/26682/ninamekaw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-04-23**:
It would help a lot if you first describe your problems. What are you doing? What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

change into the catkin_ws/src directory and type "git clone [https://github.com/KumarRobotics/flir_gige.git"](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/flir_gige.git%22)  after downloading, change into catkin_ws directory and type "catkin_make". This should build flir_gige, the e-bus sdk you need to download from pleora and install it, like described

hope this does the job

EDIT: like the error tells you, you need to install e-bus, its mentioned in the README file of flir_gige.

---

Originally posted by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) with karma: 406 on 2016-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ninamekaw](https://answers.ros.org/users/26682/ninamekaw/) on 2016-04-24**:
Thank you very much!
Downloading to ./catkin_ws/src worked but after doing the catkin_make in directory ./catkin_ws I get this [Error](https://goo.gl/AqjVmO). I've done everything in the README except [Running the Node](https://goo.gl/RtQvkJ).

What have I done wrong? How do I continue?
Again, thank

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-04-24**:
Please update your question and copy the error message there. Otherwise, the answer here will be useless for others if the image hoster removes the image.